# ElementaryOS doesn't accept any kind of port forwarding

Tags: networking

I have been attempting to open port on my laptop running eOS, I made sure the UFW was turned off.

`$ sudo ufw status Status: inactive`

Before when I was using different kind of Linux distributions, ports were working absolutely fine.

Does eOS have limitations when it comes to remote access? are there settings other than UFW to consider?